# Angular 8 lazy loaded routes and guards

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm just trying the new Angular 8 and I'm updating an old angular 6 project.

To enable lazy module loading, instead of having all the routes in the single app-routing.module.ts in the root of the project, I moved them on specific folders with relative module. For example

```
user (folder)
-----> user.module.ts
-----> detail (folder)
      -----> detail.component.ts
      -----> detail.component.html
```

and in app-routing.module.ts I lazy load the routes as:

```
{
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
}
```

Inside user.module.ts I declare the routes as:

```
const userRoutes = RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '',
        component: UserComponent,
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'detail',
                component: UserDetailComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]);
```

Now the problem: children can be activated by AuthGuard which check if the user is authenticated. 
User authentication is on a service (AuthService) and the property **isAuthenticated** is a Subject, so every time I login I do

```
this.isAuthenticated.next(true)
```

and vice versa, when I logout

```
this.isAuthenticated.next(false)
```

The first time I do login, every works fine. If I logout and login again, I got redirected to login page, even if the login was successful.

In fact, if in the Auth Guard I subscribe to

```
this.authService.isAuthenticated.subscribe(console.log)
```

the first time I can see in the console the output of "true" when I login, and "false" when i logout. When I try to login again, this subscription is not triggered.

I suspect the culprit of this is the lazy loading of the user module.

Needless to say, on Angular 6 it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Try a tool called argury to chek

Comment: @emotionlessbananas thanks for the suggestion. I think do you intend angular augury from rangle.io?

Comment: sorry for spelling mistake, Yes I intended that

Comment: Google autocorrected :) Thanks for the tool, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

May I be damned.

In order to move to lay module loading, I followed this guide

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

But I forgot to export the RouterModule in the end. Now all works perfectly.